# Counting items from a .txt file and displaying results - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox, streamreader

I'm sure I'm making this much harder than it really is, but my brain hurts....

I have a program that reads a list of baseball teams from a .txt file (called Teams) and displays them into a listbox. I have another .txt file (called WorldSeries) that displays, in order, which teams have won the World Series. The WorldSeries file looks like this (minus the bullet points):

- Boston Americans
- New York Giants
- Chicago White Sox
- Chicago Cubs
- Chicago Cubs
- Pittsburgh Pirates
- ...

Meaning The Boston Americans won the first World Series, Giants second, White Sox third, etc. The dates range from 1903-2009 accordingly, however there was no World Series in 1904 or 1994.

The program allows you to select a team from the list box, click a button, and a MessageBox tells you how many times that team has won the World Series. I thought it sounded pretty easy, but I'm having a harder time than I thought I would. I think I'm doing it way wrong. Can someone please help. Thanks!

```
    private int numberWins(int[] iArray) // Method to count total number of wins
    {
        int totalWins = 0; // Accumulator, intitialized to 0.

        // Step through the array, adding each element to the Accumulator
        for (int index = 0; index < iArray.Length; index++)
        {
            totalWins += iArray[index];
        }
        // Return the number of wins
        return numberWins;
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void worldSeriesApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string teamName; // To hold the teams name
            StreamReader inputTeams; // For file input
            inputTeams = File.OpenText("Teams.txt"); // Open the file for  team list
            teamList.Items.Clear(); // Clear all items currently in the List Box
            while (!inputTeams.EndOfStream) // While not at the end of the list of teams
            {
                teamName = inputTeams.ReadLine(); // Read each line
                teamList.Items.Add(teamName); // Add each line to the List Box
            }
            inputTeams.Close(); // Close the file
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // Catch any errors
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // Let the user know there is an error
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Local variables
        const int SEASONS = 104; // Number of Seasons between 1903 and 2009
        int[] championships = new int [SEASONS]; // Array of seasons
        StreamReader champFile; // For file input

        int index = 0; // Loop counter

        string selectedTeam; // Team selected from the List Box


        // Open the file and get StreamReader object
        champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeries.txt");

        //Read the files contents into the array
        while (index < championships.Length && !champFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            championships[index] = int.Parse(champFile.ReadLine());
            index ++;
        }

        if (teamList.SelectedIndex !=-1) // If a team is selected
        {
            //Get the selected item.
            selectedTeam = teamList.SelectedItem.ToString();

            // Determine if the team is in the array.
            if (numberWins(champFile, selectedTeam) != 1) // If so...
            {
                // Display how many times that team has won the World Series
                MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series"
                numberWins + "times!");
            }
            else // Otherwise..
            {
                // Let them know their team sucks.
                MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "sucks because they have never
                won the World Series!");
            }
```

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't, or not happening that should?

Comment: Something that you definitely need to fix:  in your first method, you're returning `numberWins` where you need to return `totalWins`.

Comment: Thanks Ann L. My error is in the last if statement. Not sure what to do

Comment: The one that calls `numberWins`?  You defined that as taking an array of ints as its parameter.  You are passing in (I think) a file handle and a string.  That's not even going to compile.

Comment: agreed, the code as is will not compile at all.

Comment: If you'd like my recommendation:  rather than writing out all the code and then trying to compile, write a little bit at a time and try to get that little bit working.  Then expand on that, adding more functionality. This will save you time and confusion, as you'll know that certain parts work when you move on to the next ones.

Comment: That's some great advice. Thanks Ann L. I Most of the time I can see the logic behind this stuff, but tonight my head is somewhere else. Lol I'll get it figured out eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

1. The statement `if (numberWins(champFile, selectedTeam) != 1)` is going to fail if a team won 2, 3, 4, etc. world series. This should be >= 1.
2. The "numberWins" function takes a list of integers, but you are calling it with two arguments, which will fail compilation.
3. The "numberWins" function itself doesn't make any sense, you are accumulating every value in the array, not checking for a team name at all. It should look like:

   ```
   int numberWins(string teamName, string[] allChampions)
   {
      int numTitles = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < allChampions.Length; i++)
      {
         if (allChampions[i] == teamName)
           numTitles++;
       }

       return numTitles;
    }
   ```
4. The while loop to read the file doesn't make any sense, you are reading a list of team names into an integer array! Make championships a string array, and change your loop to:

   ```
   while (index < championships.Length && !champFile.EndOfStream)
   {
       championships[index] = champFile.ReadLine();
       index ++;
   }
   ```

then call numberWins as `numberWins(selectedTeam, championships);`

Fixing those should get you closer. I will edit if I notice anything else.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to peice together come two bits of code from older programs that did similar things, so I was hoping it would work. Apparently, I was quite a bit off. I'll work on fixing that stuff now. Thanks!

Comment: Updated formatting, hopefully it will be more useful now

Comment: Should I keep numberWins as a method? I made those changes, but I still have the same error in my last if statement. :/

Comment: See number four, you are trying to pass a file handle instead of a string array.

Comment: Starting from scratch (especially with such a small app) and building small, compilable, and correct chunks at a time is definitely a good approach to get this working, and is a good way to learn what you are doing rather than trying to fix someone else's mistakes.

Comment: Yes. I believe you are right. I just need to start over and do this the right way. I was trying to do this too fast . Thank you for your help LordTakkera